# T-SQL inserting record while loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, while-loop, record

I want to insert a record into another table (ten_split) until the value exceeds a value in the End_loc field from the start_table. The idea is to split the records in the start_table into 10m segments.

start_table looks like below:

```
ID   Start_loc   End_loc
 1    0           40
 2    0           35
```

I want the ten_split table to look like below based on the start_table:

```
UID  ID  start_new  end_new
 1    1   0          10
 2    1   10         20
 3    1   20         30
 4    1   30         40
 5    2   0          10
 6    2   10         20
 7    2   20         30
 8    2   30         40
```

I am using Microsoft T-SQL. I am new to using loops and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, since you're using sql server, you can use a recursive cte:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5368/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table start_table (id int, start_loc int, end_loc int);

insert into start_table values (1, 0, 40);
insert into start_table values (2, 0, 35);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with recursivecte as (
  select id, 0 as start_loc, 10 as end_loc
  from start_table
  union all 
  select s.id, r.start_loc+10, r.end_loc+10
  from start_table s
    join recursivecte r on s.id = r.id
  where r.end_loc < s.end_loc
  )
select * from recursivecte
order by id, start_loc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5368/2/0)**:

```
| id | start_loc | end_loc |
|----|-----------|---------|
|  1 |         0 |      10 |
|  1 |        10 |      20 |
|  1 |        20 |      30 |
|  1 |        30 |      40 |
|  2 |         0 |      10 |
|  2 |        10 |      20 |
|  2 |        20 |      30 |
|  2 |        30 |      40 |
```

Comment: @Benjie98 I only edited the post to reformat, you should accept the answer as the accepted answer so sgeddes gets the credit